# How resolve trigonometric equations using $\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta = 1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm can not realize this exercise. How can I conclude that $$\sin (\pi/4)=\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ using the fundamental formula of trigonometry $$\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta = 1?$$

Comment: What fundamental formula are you referring to?

Comment: Problem has typo: should be $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  The key is that in a $45 - 45 - 90$ triangle, the *slope* of the hypotenuse is $1$, so the two legs are the same size.  This means that if each leg has length $n$, then the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{2(n^2)} = n\sqrt{2}.$  This means that $\sin(\pi/4) = \frac{n}{n\sqrt{2}}.$

Comment: Assuming you know that $\sin(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$, then $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, so $\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you're willing to assume. If you are willing to assume that
$$\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$$
then the solution is quite simple. This assumption is quite reasonable, since an isosceles right angled triangle will certainly have $2$ angles being equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians by basic geometry.
$$\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1\iff \frac{\sin(\pi/4)}{\cos(\pi/4)}=1\iff\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Using the identity above ($\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv 1$):
$$\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}+\cos^2\frac{\pi}{4}=1\iff2\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}=1\iff\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$
as required (using the fact that $\sin x$ is positive for $x$ in the first $2$ quadrants).

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 3):

Draw an isosceles right triangle sides $(1,1, \sqrt2 ).$

Sine is defined as opposite side divided by hypotenuse of side length $\sqrt2$

$$ \sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}= \sin  45^{\circ}=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$